# Error connecting with SSL using Indy and Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I'm trying to submit JSON via post on a given URL, but i keep getting the error:

```
'Error connecting with SSL. error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version'.
```

I'm using the property SSLVersions to specify the version (sslvTLSv1_2) and i checked manually using Firefox certificate viewer to confirm the version was correct. I also updated OpenSSL with the latest version using their installer as recommended on Delphi's help.

Besides the version, i barely touched any other property from both TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and TIdHTTP.

I'm trying on Delphi 10.2 Tokyo using Indy built-in basic authentication as a custom header

Are there any other properties i should change or look into in order to succesfully post?

Thank you!

Comment: "I also updated OpenSSL with the latest version using their installer as recommended on Delphi's help" From where, exactly?

Comment: http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: Make sure you install 1.0.2o. I'm pretty sure Indy does not support 1.1.x yet

Comment: Thank you very much, i downgraded and everything worked properly! Wasn't aware that Indy didn't support 1.1.0

Comment: @DaveNottage "*I'm pretty sure Indy does not support 1.1.x yet*" - [that is correct](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/183). FYI, OpenSSL DLLs that are known to be compatible with Indy are available on Indy's Fulgan mirror: http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Answer (score 3):

As Dave pointed out in comments, I was using the newest version of OpenSSL 1.1.x, which isn't supported by Indy. I downgraded to 1.0.2o, and everything worked out!